# how can I return a hash value using keccak256?

Tags: solidity, keccak

I have this solidity function below. It is supposed to return the hash of a given data, but instead I get this: **0x**

```
 function hashData (bytes32 data) public constant returns (bytes32) {
      var hash =  keccak256(data);
      return hash;
  }
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Works for me as well, have you put the data in like so `"data"` and also instead of using `var hash` try using `bytes32 hash`

Comment: it doesn't work for byte32 also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hashData (bytes32 data) public pure returns (bytes32) {
      bytes32 hash =  keccak256(data);
      return hash;
  }
```

hope this helps